Labelling the latitude and longitude on both axis. and increasing their fontsize
I have a simple code to create a pygmt map. However, I am not able to change the fontsize of the Latitude/longitude labels .
The sample code is here.
import pygmt
fig = pygmt.Figure()

grid = pygmt.datasets.load_earth_relief(resolution="20m", region=[50,65,10,25])
pygmt.makecpt(series=[-8000,4000])

fig.grdimage(grid=grid, projection="M15c", frame="a", cmap="geo",dpi=300)
fig.grdcontour(grid=grid,projection="M15c", levels=1000,frame="a")
fig.colorbar(frame=["a1000f100", "x+lDepth/Elevation (m)", "y+lm"], position="g51/6+w13c/0.5c+h")
fig.show()

In my understanding, I did mess around but couldn't find any solution.

To change the GMT default parameters locally, pygmt.config can be used together with a context manager. You can use Figure.basemap to set up a basic map.
import pygmt

projection = "M15c"
region = [50, 65, 10, 25]
grid = pygmt.datasets.load_earth_relief(resolution="20m", region=region)


fig = pygmt.Figure()

with pygmt.config(FONT="20p"):
    fig.basemap(region=region, projection=projection, frame="a")

fig.grdimage(grid=grid, cmap="geo", dpi=300)
fig.grdcontour(grid=grid, levels=1000)
fig.colorbar(
    frame=["a1000f100", "x+lDepth/Elevation (m)", "y+lm"],
    position="g51/6+w13c/0.5c+h",
)

fig.show()




Reading the title there seems to be another question:

Labelling the latitude and longitude on both axis

Do you mean left and right as well as top and bottom? This can be done using the frame parameter. We have a PyGMT tutorial on this, whereby the section at https://www.pygmt.org/v0.12.0/tutorials/basics/frames.html#axis-labels explains in detail what you probably need.
import pygmt

projection = "M8c"
region = [50, 65, 10, 25]

fig = pygmt.Figure()

fig.basemap(region=region, projection=projection, frame="a")

fig.shift_origin(xshift="+w+2c")

fig.basemap(region=region, projection=projection, frame=["WSNE", "a"])

fig.show()



thank you @yvonnefroehlich . I am coming to an understanding that "frame ='a' " isn't necessary to be given at every subsequent command like as in  grdimage, grdcontour etc.

@RanjanKumarSahu thats's correct! The same holds for the region and projection parameters.

Looks like the easiest way is to use pygmt.config(FONT="20p") as follows, it does change all of your text size though.
import pygmt

fig = pygmt.Figure()
pygmt.config(FONT="20p")

grid = pygmt.datasets.load_earth_relief(resolution="20m", region=[50,65,10,25])
pygmt.makecpt(series=[-8000,4000])

fig.grdimage(grid=grid, projection="M15c", frame="a", cmap="geo",dpi=300)
fig.grdcontour(grid=grid,projection="M15c", levels=1000,frame="a")
fig.colorbar(frame=["a1000f100", "x+lDepth/Elevation (m)", "y+lm"], position="g51/6+w13c/0.5c+h")

fig.show()

